# replacing key object for the array values

Tags: json, loops, object, ecmascript-6, key

Im having a problem with replacing keys in object

```
let headers = ['title1', 'title2', 'title3']

let obj = {
    0: ['name1', 'name2, 'name3],
    1: ['example1', 'example2, 'example3],
    2: ['xx', 'yy, 'zz],
}
```

What I'm trying to do is:

```
let obj = {
   'title1': ['name1', 'name2, 'name3],
   'title2': ['example1', 'example2, 'example3],
   'title3': ['xx', 'yy, 'zz],
}
```

I'm not sure if my approach is correct:

```
  Object.keys(obj).map((el, index, arr) => {
      headers.forEach((item, item_index) => {
          arr[item_index] = item
      })
  })
```

When I `console.log(Object.keys(obj))` I'm still getting: `0,1,2` ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) returns only values from specified `obj` and [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) allows you to create a new object based on two-element list of arrays:

```js
let headers = ['title1', 'title2', 'title3'];

let obj = {
    0: ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'],
    1: ['example1', 'example2', 'example3'],
    2: ['xx', 'yy', 'zz']
};

let result = Object.fromEntries(Object.values(obj).map((v,i) => ([headers[i], v])));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you're not mutating your object, you're mutating an array of keys that `Object.keys` returned you, which makes no sense. Here's how you can do it:

```js
const headers = ['title1', 'title2', 'title3']

const obj = {
    0: ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'],
    1: ['example1', 'example2', 'example3'],
    2: ['xx', 'yy', 'zz'],
}

const renameObj = (obj, keys) => {
  return keys.reduce((acc, key, index) => ({ ...acc, [key]: obj[index] }), {})
}

console.log(renameObj(obj, headers))
```

Hope it helps <3